# Mininet : Creating a host with multiple interfaces and assigning IP address using addLink()

Tags: python, mininet

I want to create a network with 2 hosts connected to each other via 3
links (each link belonging to a different network)

```
   _________10.0.0.0/31 network________________
  |                                            |
H1+---------10.0.1.0/31 network----------------+H2
  | ________10.0.2.0/31 network----------------|
```

I followed [the solution given in the mininet mailing list](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2015-March/005895.html)
to try and add the links.

> `self.addLink( 'h1', s1, params1={'ip':'10.3/8'} )`

While the hosts do get 3 interfaces only one
of the interfaces gets assigned the default IP 10.0.0.1/8
I dug through the source code and the way I did it should work but I don't understand why mine doesn't

```py
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.link import TCLink, Link
from mininet.net import Mininet

class MyTopo( Topo ):
    "Simple topology example."

    def __init__( self ):
        "Create custom topo."

        # Initialize topology
        Topo.__init__( self )

        # Add hosts and switches
        lH = self.addHost( 'h1' )
        rH = self.addHost( 'h2')

        # Add links
        self.addLink(lH, rH, bw = 10, delay='50ms', params1={ 'ip' : '10.0.0.1/31' }, params2={ 'ip' : '10.0.0.2/31' })
        self.addLink(lH, rH, bw = 1, delay='200ms', params1={ 'ip' : '10.1.0.1/31' }, params2={ 'ip' : '10.1.0.2/31' })
        self.addLink(lH,rH, bw = 0.1, delay='500ms',  params1={ 'ip' : '10.2.0.1/31' }, params2={ 'ip' : '10.2.0.2/31' })

topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to pass `intf=TCIntf` to the `addLink()` function and pass the appropriate arguments

```py
self.addLink(lH, rH, intf=TCIntf,  params1={'delay':'50ms', 'bw' : 10, 'ip' : '10.0.0.1/24' }
```